# JavaScript Toggle button for multiple divs - separately

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I've got a .jsp file with loop inside, which prints many objects of same type send from servlet. I want to display only one field of every object, and expand it and show rest of informations on click. Is there any simple way to achieve it in vanilla js?

Comment: Have you tried using the html elements: `<detail>` and `<summary>`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Comment: works nice, but my goal is to use javascript

Comment: Okay, so when you say expand the rest of the fields from the object which do you want:
* Have the fields all be rendered in HTML and then use JS to show them on click, or
* Use JS to add them into the HTML after click

Comment: whatever, it has to work fast.